# passing credential in HttpWebRequest In UrabanCode Deploy

Tags: httprequest, credentials, urbancode

I am using HttpwebRequest to pull list of all Components from Urban-code Deploy to my application. I have used my own credential in the code(C#) to access it. It is working fine. Now, i have to use the Service account that my company has, in order to pass the credential. I tried using DefaultCredential and defaultNetworkcredential but getting same error--Unauthorized access. Any help!!!  Thank u!!!

Answer (score 0):

You got an answer on the UrbanCode forum here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/372586/authentication-using-service-account-without-admin/?smartspace=urbancode

You just need a user account in the system with permissions to access the data. Accessing data via REST API requires the same permissions as through the UI. There's no way to bypass that.